# SGE Fast Forward Job Numbers

Tags: sungridengine, qsub

Is there some way in SGE to advance / fast forward the job number counter? I would like to have the number set initially to something higher than 1.

Comment: Would be useful if you provide specific scenario as well as motivation as to why you want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly supported but in the spool for your cluster there is a file called jobseqnum.   It should be possible to stop the qmaster, edit this file to taste and restart the qmaster.